# Automating Creation of VM through python-libvirt and Providing SSH access

Tags: ssh, virtualization, automation, network-bridge, libvirt

For a Project I am trying to automate the Process of generating Virtual Machines through libvirt using python-libvirt. Using the following dump.xml I create a VM.

```
dump.xml
<domain type="kvm" id="3">
<name>{0}</name>
<uuid>{1}</uuid>
<metadata>
<libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
<libosinfo:os id="http://ubuntu.com/ubuntu/22.04"/>
</libosinfo:libosinfo>
</metadata>
<memory unit="KiB">{2}</memory>
<currentMemory unit="KiB">{3}</currentMemory>
<vcpu placement="static">{4}</vcpu>
<resource>
<partition>/machine</partition>
</resource>
<os>
<type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-6.2">hvm</type>
<boot dev="cdrom"/>
<boot dev="hd"/>
</os>
<features>
<acpi/>
<apic/>
<vmport state="off"/>
</features>
<cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on"/>
<clock offset="utc">
<timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
<timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
<timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
</clock>
<on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
<on_reboot>destroy</on_reboot>
<on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
<pm>
<suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
<suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
</pm>
<devices>
<emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
<disk type="file" device="disk">
<driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" discard="unmap"/>
<source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/Capstone-generateXML.qcow2" index="2"/>
<backingStore/>
<target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
<alias name="virtio-disk0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>
<disk type="file" device="cdrom">
<driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
<source file="{5}" index="1"/>
<backingStore/>
<target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
<readonly/>
<alias name="sata0-0-0"/>
<address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
</disk>
<controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
<alias name="usb"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root">
<alias name="pcie.0"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
<alias name="pci.1"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
<alias name="pci.2"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
<alias name="pci.3"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
<alias name="pci.4"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
<alias name="pci.5"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
<alias name="pci.6"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="7" port="0x16"/>
<alias name="pci.7"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x6"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="8" port="0x17"/>
<alias name="pci.8"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x7"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="9" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="9" port="0x18"/>
<alias name="pci.9"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="10" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="10" port="0x19"/>
<alias name="pci.10"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x1"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="11" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="11" port="0x1a"/>
<alias name="pci.11"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x2"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="12" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="12" port="0x1b"/>
<alias name="pci.12"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x3"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="13" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="13" port="0x1c"/>
<alias name="pci.13"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x4"/>
</controller>
<controller type="pci" index="14" model="pcie-root-port">
<model name="pcie-root-port"/>
<target chassis="14" port="0x1d"/>
<alias name="pci.14"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x5"/>
</controller>
<controller type="sata" index="0">
<alias name="ide"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
</controller>
<controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
<alias name="virtio-serial0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</controller>
<interface type="bridge">
<mac address="52:54:00:ca:94:c3"/>
<source network="{6}" bridge="virbr0"/>
<target dev="vnet2"/>
<model type="virtio"/>
<alias name="net0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
<serial type="pty">
<source path="/dev/pts/4"/>
<target type="isa-serial" port="0">
<model name="isa-serial"/>
</target>
<alias name="serial0"/>
</serial>
<console type="pty" tty="/dev/pts/4">
<source path="/dev/pts/4"/>
<target type="serial" port="0"/>
<alias name="serial0"/>
</console>
<channel type="unix">
<source mode="bind" path="/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-3-Capstone-generateXML/org.qemu.guest_agent.0"/>
<target type="virtio" name="org.qemu.guest_agent.0" state="disconnected"/>
<alias name="channel0"/>
<address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
</channel>
<channel type="spicevmc">
<target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0" state="disconnected"/>
<alias name="channel1"/>
<address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="2"/>
</channel>
<input type="tablet" bus="usb">
<alias name="input0"/>
<address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
</input>
<input type="mouse" bus="ps2">
<alias name="input1"/>
</input>
<input type="keyboard" bus="ps2">
<alias name="input2"/>
</input>
<graphics type="spice" port="5902" autoport="yes" listen="127.0.0.1">
<listen type="address" address="127.0.0.1"/>
<image compression="off"/>
</graphics>
<graphics type="vnc" port="{7}"/>
<sound model="ich9">
<alias name="sound0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
</sound>
<audio id="1" type="spice"/>
<video>
<model type="qxl" ram="65536" vram="65536" vgamem="16384" heads="1" primary="yes"/>
<alias name="video0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</video>
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
<alias name="redir0"/>
<address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
</redirdev>
<redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
<alias name="redir1"/>
<address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
</redirdev>
<memballoon model="virtio">
<alias name="balloon0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</memballoon>
<rng model="virtio">
<backend model="random">/dev/urandom</backend>
<alias name="rng0"/>
<address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</rng>
</devices>
<seclabel type="dynamic" model="apparmor" relabel="yes">
<label>libvirt-4bbb0bbf-549a-47b9-adf1-bedb51da79a0</label>
<imagelabel>libvirt-4bbb0bbf-549a-47b9-adf1-bedb51da79a0</imagelabel>
</seclabel>
<seclabel type="dynamic" model="dac" relabel="yes">
<label>+0:+0</label>
<imagelabel>+0:+0</imagelabel>
</seclabel>
</domain>
```

I have few concers or I would say blocks.
After I created the VM I would like to give SSH access to a user in the same network but from different machine. So I tried to install openSSH-server and tried to ssh into it. It didn't work although I had given bridge network thorugh the GUI of VMM.

**1) Why is it bridge network is not working.**
ifconfig doesn't show any ipv4 address and no internet is accessible in the machine.

**2) If internet and SSH worked. How do I automate the process of installing openSSH-server and giving acess to other users.**
After creating VM through python-libvirt I was only login through the GUI (VMM) to do anyfurther actions. I am unaware of how to move forward so that openSSH is intalled. and getting the IP for SSH.